# When initializing a class, AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '[parametername]'

Tags: python, class

In Python, when defining a class that accepts a parameter in its `__init__` method:

```
class animal:  
  number_of_legs = 0

  def __init__(nlegs, self):
    self.number_of_legs = nlegs

a = animal(3)
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'number_of_legs'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
def __init__(nlegs, self):
```

to:

```
def __init__(self, nlegs):
```

Because in your code instance gets assigned to `nlegs` and 3 gets  assigned to `self`.

You should place `self` as the first argument in class methods.